# Why is my Toplevel() widget freezing my program on Windows but not ubuntu?

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, ubuntu, tkinter

I have some source that i hammered out this weekend that is supposed to be a personal time management program for work.  The modules used are, Tkinter, time, thread, textwrap and datetime.

I finished it up last night thinking it was 100% working because it ran just fine on my Ubuntu boxes.  Now that i'm at work, when i use my windows box, the alert window i'm trying to spawn with the Toplevel() widget freezes the entire program.  I have no idea why this is.  I only have been learning Tkinter and the thread module this weekend, so I don't know if windows handles things differently than ubuntu in regards to Tkinter and the thread module.  I assumed they would be the same.

The problem occurs after i start a thread on the message_box() function i have created in my source.  When it runs this function on my windows machine, it does not print my "Starting Toplevel()" into the console after the:

```
eb = Toplevel()
```

command, which leads me to believe that for some reason it isn't initiating properly?  I have no idea why this would happen on my windows machine, but work fine on my linux machine.  The command i use to start the thread is:

```
thread.start_new_thread(message_box,(comp_msg,""))
```

The message_box Function:

```
#Spawns Error Box.  Runs in it's own thread.
def message_box(comp_msg,q):
    print "Spawning Error Box..."
    eb = Toplevel(master=None)
    print "Starting Toplevel()"
    eb.config(bg="black")
    eb.title("ALERT!")

    fr = Frame(eb)
    fr.configure(bg="black")

    wrapped = textwrap.wrap(comp_msg, 45)
    comp_msg = "\n".join(wrapped)

    pop_l = Label(fr,font=("Times New Roman",50),text="ALERT!!!")
    pop_l.config(bg="black",fg="red")

    if len(comp_msg) < 17:
        pop_l2=Label(fr,font=("Times New Roman",26),text=comp_msg)
    elif len(comp_msg) < 30 and len(comp_msg) > 16:
        pop_l2=Label(fr,font=("Times New Roman",18),text=comp_msg)
    else:
        pop_l2=Label(fr,font=("Times New Roman",16),text=comp_msg)

    pop_l2.config(fg="yellow",bg="black")
    pop_l3 = Label(fr,text="")
    pop_l3.config(bg="black",fg="black")

    pop_l.pack(pady=7,padx=10)
    pop_l2.pack(padx=15)
    pop_l3.pack()
    fr.pack()
    return eb
```

[Full source](http://pastebin.com/3CmqmWXw)

Any help is greatly appreciated.  I am really somewhat lost as to why this would happen, but i am also new to Tkinter module, thread module, and GUI programming in general.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter isn't thread safe. You should only create and access widgets from a single thread.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how i might get my program to work on Windows?  I'm seriously confused as to how anyone can program a GUI in python when i cannot find any way to run functions and the GUI at the same time.  the second the function that monitors the time kicks in, the program will not do anything. Somehow, i need my program monitoring the time and at the same time it needs to accept input.  I was also told that threading is how i am supposed to accomplish this.  I'm seriously confused at this point.  I'm getting information from several sources who seem to contradict eachother :(

Comment: @Wykleph: what do you mean by "monitoring the time"? If all you're doing is checking the time periodically, there's no need for a thread. You can use `after` to run something every few milliseconds, if what you're doing takes only a few hundred milliseconds to run. If you really need threads, put all of your GUI code in one thread, and your non-GUI code in another.

Comment: I honestly don't know if i need to monitor the time...  What i need to do is set several user-specified times that will trigger a Toplevel() widget to create a error-type alert for the user once the time comes. I think you answered my question once i asked it in another way.  I was taking what i had heard from others and trying to implement what they told me.  I just didn't realize that my goal was based off of information that might not be entirely accurate as you have pointed out.  I'll let you know what happens once i get home and start working on that timer.  Thanks again!